# Why do I get this message whenever I open a terminal?

Tags: logs

I keep getting this strange message when I open a terminal:

```
me@batcuter:~$ 
Message from syslogd@batcuter at Apr 21 14:10:38 ...
  such IMContext

Message from syslogd@batcuter at Apr 21 14:10:38 ...
  such IMContext

Message from syslogd@batcuter at Apr 21 14:10:43 ...
  invalid char is given at scim_bridge_string_to_uint (): -

Message from syslogd@batcuter at Apr 21 14:10:43 ...
 valid message: Close the connection.
```

I have no idea what's happening...

1. Where can I read these logs?
2. Should I be afraid of a malicious cyberattack?

Comment: Do you have package called scim-bridge installed? If so, uninstall it. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scim-bridge/+bug/573103 based on googling the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in SCIM, I have read that you can "disable SCIM by switching execution permission of script /etc/profile.d/scim.(c)sh" - this is probably distribution-specific.

The reason that the messages appear on your terminal can be found by inspecting /etc/syslogd.conf.

That file also controls which log files the messages are also written to.

It is a software fault, not a malicious cyberattack.